# Loop through table to input a where condition into a delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am running SQL Server 2012.

I have two tables:

table 1 [dbo].FilestoUpdate - this file records to test for duplicates:

```
[ID]     [A_number]
 1         A069467
 2         A078594
 3         A085473
etc          etc
```

table 2 which contain all my data:
I am deleting duplicate records in table 2 employing the following query:

```
;WITH Vals AS (SELECT [A_number]
  ,[Date]
  ,[ZONE]
  ,[MGA_N]
  ,[MGA_E]
  ,[MI_SQL_Y]
  ,[MI_SQL_X]
  ,[RL]
  ,[SHEET_100K]
  ,[SHEET_250K]
  ,[Hole_ID]
  ,[Sample_Group]
  ,[Sample_No]
  ,[Mesh_Size]
  ,[Sample_Type]
  ,[DEPTH]
  ,[Au_ppb]
  ,[Au_limit]
  ,[Au_meth]
  ,[Ag_ppm]
  ,[Ag_limit]
  ,[Ag_meth]
  ,[As_ppm]
  ,[As_limit]
  ,[As_meth]
  ,[Cu_ppm]
  ,[Cu_limit]
  ,[Cu_meth]
  ,[Ni_ppm]
  ,[Ni_limit]
  ,[Ni_meth]
  ,[Co_ppm]
  ,[Co_limit]
  ,[Co_meth]
  ,[Pb_ppm]
  ,[Pb_limit]
  ,[Pb_meth]
  ,[Zn_ppm]
  ,[Zn_limit]
  ,[Zn_meth]
  ,[Lithology]
  ,[Comments]
  ,[CompositeID]
  ,[SourcefileName]
  ,[Coordinate_ID]
  ,[Priority]
  ,[myStyle]
  ,[MI_PRINX]
  ,therow = row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Coordinate_ID] ORDER BY [Coordinate_ID]  DESC)
  FROM [DRILLHOLES_Export].[dbo].[WAMEX_Soil_Live]
  WHERE [A_number] = 'A069467'
)

DELETE FROM VALS
WHERE  therow > 1;
```

I want to loop through table1 (`FilestoUpate`) an run the query with each `a_number` eg 'A069467' then 'A078594' then 'A085473 ete etc.

Is this possible?

Regards,

Peter

Comment: I am not good enough with SQL to be guided by your clues; could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. SQL operates on sets of data so you would have to build a set of data with rows you want to delete:

```
DELETE table_to_delete 
  FROM [DRILLHOLES_Export].[dbo].[WAMEX_Soil_Live] table_to_delete 
    INNER JOIN [DRILLHOLES_Export].[dbo].[FilestoUpate] table_with_keys 
      ON table_to_delete.[A_number]=table_with_keys.[A_number]
```

You have to also provide information about where do you wan to remove data from: table_to_delete